# Is is possible to animate text color changing only in a part of text in iOS?

Tags: ios, uilabel, nsattributedstring, core-text

I wonder if it even possible in iOS to animate changing color in only a part of the text, preferably not char by char, but pixel by pixel, like on this picture?

[image]

I know how to change text color in static with NSAttributedString and I know how to animate the whole text with CADisplayLink, but this makes me worry.

Maybe I can dive into CoreText, but I'm still not sure it is possible even with it. Any thoughts?

UPD I decided to add a video with my first results to make the question more clear:

[my efforts for now (the label is overlapping)](https://gph.is/g/ZlRVLoY)

Comment: Interesting question, have you found a solution?

Comment: @Frankenstein thanks, if I find any, I will post it here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can quite easily achieve this using CoreAnimation possibilities.
I've added a simple demo, you play with it [here](https://github.com/gatamar/stackoverflow_answers/tree/master/so61984099) (just build the project and tap anywhere to see the animation).

The logic is the following:

1. Create a custom subclass of UIView.
2. When some text is set, create two similar `CATextLayers`, each with the same text and frame.
3. Set different `foregroundColor` and `mask` for those layers. The `mask` of the left layer will be the left part of the view, and the `mask` of the right layer will be the right part.
4. Animate `foregroundColor` for those layers (simultaneously).

The code of a custom view:

```
class CustomTextLabel: UIView {
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        backgroundColor = .green
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    private var textLayer1: CATextLayer?
    private var textLayer2: CATextLayer?

    func setText(_ text: String, fontSize: CGFloat) {
        // create 2 layers with the same text and size, we'll set the colors for them later
        textLayer1 = createTextLayer(text, fontSize: fontSize)
        textLayer2 = createTextLayer(text, fontSize: fontSize)

        // estimate the frame size needed for the text layer with such text and font size
        let textSize = textLayer1!.preferredFrameSize()
        let w = frame.width, h = frame.height

        // calculate the frame such that both layers will be in center of view
        let centeredTextFrame = CGRect(x: (w-textSize.width)/2, y: (h-textSize.height)/2, width: textSize.width, height: textSize.height)
        textLayer1!.frame = centeredTextFrame
        textLayer2!.frame = centeredTextFrame

        // set up default color for the text
        textLayer1!.foregroundColor = UIColor.yellow.cgColor
        textLayer2!.foregroundColor = UIColor.yellow.cgColor

        // set background transparent, that's very important
        textLayer1!.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        textLayer2!.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor

        // set up masks, such that each layer's text is visible only in its part
        textLayer1!.mask = createMaskLayer(CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: textSize.width/2, height: textSize.height))
        textLayer2!.mask = createMaskLayer(CGRect(x: textSize.width/2, y: 0, width: textSize.width/2, height: textSize.height))

        layer.addSublayer(textLayer1!)
        layer.addSublayer(textLayer2!)
    }

    private var finishColor1: UIColor = .black, finishColor2: UIColor = .black
    func animateText(leftPartColor1: UIColor, leftPartColor2: UIColor, rightPartColor1: UIColor, rightPartColor2: UIColor) {
        finishColor1 = leftPartColor2
        finishColor2 = rightPartColor2

        if let layer1 = textLayer1, let layer2 = textLayer2 {
            CATransaction.begin()
            let animation1 = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "foregroundColor")
            animation1.fromValue = leftPartColor1.cgColor
            animation1.toValue = leftPartColor2.cgColor
            animation1.duration = 3.0
            layer1.add(animation1, forKey: "animation1")


            let animation2 = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "foregroundColor")
            animation2.fromValue = rightPartColor1.cgColor
            animation2.toValue = rightPartColor2.cgColor
            animation2.duration = 3.0
            layer2.add(animation2, forKey: "animation2")

            CATransaction.setCompletionBlock {
                self.textLayer1?.foregroundColor = self.finishColor1.cgColor
                self.textLayer2?.foregroundColor = self.finishColor2.cgColor
            }

            CATransaction.commit()
        }
    }

    private func createTextLayer(_ text: String, fontSize: CGFloat) -> CATextLayer {
        let textLayer = CATextLayer()
        textLayer.string = text
        textLayer.fontSize = fontSize // TODO: also set font name
        textLayer.contentsScale = UIScreen.main.scale

        return textLayer
    }

    private func createMaskLayer(_ holeRect: CGRect) -> CAShapeLayer {
        let layer = CAShapeLayer()

        let path = CGMutablePath()

        path.addRect(holeRect)
        path.addRect(bounds)

        layer.path = path
        layer.fillRule = CAShapeLayerFillRule.evenOdd
        layer.opacity = 1

        return layer
    }
}
```

The calls of a custom view:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var customLabel: CustomTextLabel!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let viewW = view.frame.width, viewH = view.frame.height
        let labelW: CGFloat = 200, labelH: CGFloat = 50

        customLabel = CustomTextLabel(frame: CGRect(x: (viewW-labelW)/2, y: (viewH-labelH)/2, width: labelW, height: labelH))
        customLabel.setText("Optimizing...", fontSize: 20)
        view.addSubview(customLabel)

        let tapRecogniner = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(onTap))
        view.addGestureRecognizer(tapRecogniner)
    }

    @objc func onTap() {
        customLabel.animateText(leftPartColor1: UIColor.blue,
                                leftPartColor2: UIColor.red,
                                rightPartColor1: UIColor.white,
                                rightPartColor2: UIColor.black)
    }

}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this was the expected result.

Comment: thank you so much for this approach, but it turned out that is not what I need. sorry, I have to unmark it as accepted answer, because it animates text in static, not in movement. I should add a gif to my question to make it more clear

Comment: have you tried to recalculate the masks for layers in my solution? only the width ratio should be changed from 0.5:0.5 to some r:1-r. i can’t guess about the performance though

Comment: I just have play with text layers and masks from your solution and I think I did it! huge thanks, I will accept your answer (again, sorry!) and I will share my final solution as well.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Olha's (@OlhaPavliuk) answer, I used two CATextLayer shapes and two CAShapeLayer masks for text layers. In draw method I just change masks frames to calculated size (bounds.width * progress value), and also change the second mask origin to a new start (bounds.width - bounds.width * progress value).

Also, it was very important to set `layer.fillRule = CAShapeLayerFillRule.evenOdd` while creating a mask, so that both layers became visible.

It turned out that I actually didn't need any animation code involved, because changing frames looks just ok.

[image]

In motion: https://giphy.com/gifs/LMbmlMoxY9oaWhXfO1

Full code: https://gist.github.com/joliejuly/a792c2ab8d97d304d731a4a5202f741a